# Return 2 things from a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, return

I am creating a football league table whereby the user can enter results of 2 teams and then it updates the table. I had it working but it started getting messy as I was firing too many actions.

I have this action case:

```
case 'UPDATE_WINNER': {
  const result = workOutWinner(action.data.homeTeam, action.data.awayTeam)
  return state.map(team => team.name === result.winners.name
    ?
    { ...team,
      won: team.won + 1,
      points: team.points + 3,
      goalsScored: team.goalsScored + result.winners.goals,
      goalsAgainst: team.goalsAgainst + result.losers.goals
    }
    : team )
}
```

and this one:

```
   case 'UPDATE_LOSER': {
      const result = workOutWinner(action.data.homeTeam, action.data.awayTeam)
      return state.map(team => team.name === result.losers.name
        ?
        { ...team,
          lost: team.lost + 1,
          goalsScored: team.goalsScored + result.losers.goals,
          goalsAgainst: team.goalsAgainst+ result.winners.goals
        }
        : team )
    }
```

I need another for when teams draw etc. I also stumbled into an issue whereby I fall all these actions every time. i.e (I don't need to call the UPDATE_IF_DRAW action if a team has won) but the current way works it after the action has been called.

I was wondering if someone could help me write a case where I can do something like UPDATE_TABLE.

I started writing this but got unstuck when I realised the following,

team A beats team B) requires 2 parts of the table being updated. i.e. one for the win and for the loss

that's why I want to return 2 things because I want to map over my state, find the team who won and update their state AND map over the team who lost and update their state.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update both of them using a conditional check in the map function like

```
case 'UPDATE_TABLE': {
      const result = workOutWinner(action.data.homeTeam, action.data.awayTeam)
      return state.map(team => team.name === result.losers.name
        ?
        { ...team,
          lost: team.lost + 1,
          goalsScored: team.goalsScored + result.losers.goals,
          goalsAgainst: team.goalsAgainst+ result.winners.goals
        }
        : team.name === result.winners.name ? 
          { ...team,
            won: team.won + 1,
            points: team.points + 3,
            goalsScored: team.goalsScored + result.winners.goals,
            goalsAgainst: team.goalsAgainst + result.losers.goals
          } : team )
    }
```

Comment: that's so cool! but I have a question. when it maps over my array and then finds the "loser" team, wont it just break out of the loop before completing? or do map functions complete regardless and therefore will map over the whole array, finding both, and then returning both?

Comment: It will not return and instead map over the entire array. That how map is designed to work, return inside map returns the data to create a new array